# Get The Response Of A PHP Script Request In .NET

Tags: php, vb.net, variables, httpwebrequest, response

hey i am making an activation architecture in .net. I have written a script that posts the PHP variables, however, the PHP echos back a server response and i want to get that response back.

I have tried some code pieces but they don't work.

the sample php script is:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['username'];

echo $name;

?>
```

i can't get the response, i.e. `echo $name`, i cant get it please help

my code is:

```
 Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    requestStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length)


    Dim stream As Stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)

    Dim response As String

    Dim newStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

    While response = reader.ReadLine()
        response += reader.ReadLine()
    End While



    Return response

    requestStream.Close()
```

thanks

Comment: What does the code of the script that returns the response look like?

Comment: Dim strem as new IO.StreamReader

Comment: Could show a little bit more than that, preferably highlighted as code in your original post?

Comment: can any one please help?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?(check if the program is valid or display the response of the script without html tags)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [my Answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656011/visual-basic-php-server/18463078#18463078).
It's a bit more complicated than the answer you need, but it will solve your problem.
The Second Example is what you want. But ***don't just copy it***, you need the **class** and the **reference** too.

Hope it helps.