# Syncing Web application and Desktop application

Tags: php, vb.net, web-applications, desktop-application

I have developed a web application and desktop application which do the same job. Web application is made using PHP and desktop application is made using Visual Basic.Net.

Actually I have to sync these two applications. I need to sync database and photos of the students.

I want to know, if it is possible to sync these applications? If possible, how to do this?
Actually I don't know how to sync the photos between the applications.I want to know, how can I transfer photos from my local computer to the website and website to local computer.

Any type of suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just get both application to share the same database - voila!

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer.But I have to make the desktop application to be able run when there is no internet connection as well. Which is not possible if I use the same database. And I need to sync the pictures uploaded through website and desktop application. :-(

Comment: Check this for POST and GET data, may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18463078/1683017