# WebBrowser Not Showing Images

Tags: vb.net, controls

On every website I attempt to visit with WebBrowser in vb.net I get the 'alt' text for the image.

[image: Example]

I didn't change any settings with WebBrowser1, so this is really strange to me.

Comment: Any other information? did you check your IE to check if you have the same problem?

Comment: Just checked Internet Explorer and I'm getting the same problem, no images are coming through.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with vb.net. your IE interface is broken.
Right click on images on IE and try to figure out the error. You fix that, and your VB.net problem will solve itself.

Comment: I have just reset all IE settings and it works 100% now; not sure what the problem was...

Comment: You may want to stop using WebBrowser for your non-Browsing purposes!
It's to buggy to use for decent coding. Use Client objects and such

Check my answer here, may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18463078/1683017