# Send and receive data from Visual Basic to PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, post

Is it possible to send Visual Basic form data to PHP and receive information back?
Here's a similar scenario of what I want to do:

- Create a form in Visual Basic with a text-box.
- Once the user has completed the form and pressed the submit button, it sends the data to a PHP script.
- The PHP script checks if if the data is numeric. If it is, it will return true and make a message box come up in the VB form saying "Yes, that is numeric"
- If it is not numeric, it will return false and make a message box come up in the VB form saying "No, that is not numeric"

Is that possible at all?

Comment: you'd just be doing http requests, which means the actual languages used on either end are irrelevant - you format the data into HTTP-accetable formats and it'll get sent/received.

Comment: so is that a yes or a no?

Comment: Sounds to me like that is a yes.

Answer (score 2):

That is a **Yes**.

For the **VB** part, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463078/1683017) here to send data (GET and/or POST) to PHP.

<sub>It is a long answer, but it's really easy</sub>

And for the **PHP** part assuming that the information was sent by *this code*:

```
Dim Page As New WEBhtml("http://www.example.com/index.php?getfrom=here", {"is=numeric"})
```

This would be the **PHP** code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['is']))
    if(is_numeric($_POST['is']))
        echo 'Yes, that is numeric';
    else
        echo 'No, that is not numeric';
else
    echo 'Say something!';
?>
```

Hope it Helps.